# Работа точки входа в java

Tags: java, main, запуск

Доброго времени суток коллеги!

Напомню в `java` точка входа выглядит так:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```

Насколько я понимаю, JRE должна всунуть какой-то массив строк, и вопрос первый - какой и почему? Вот юзер щелкнул дважды. Откуда там массив строк сгенерился? 
В IntellijIdea я набрал

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
        System.out.println(args.length);
    }
```

И ... мне вывело `0`. Второй вопрос - почему нуль? Неужели `IntellijIdea` даёт массив нулевой длины на вход при запуске?

Comment: Не совсем понятно - приоретет операий в заголовке, и собственно содержание вопроса. Между ними есть какая-то взаимосвязь?

Comment: Это не идея передает массив 0 длины, а жвм при запуске. Если вы запустите ваш код командой "java YourClass", то будет тоже самое.

Comment: Заголовок поправил. ПРОСТО ТОРОПИЛСЯ.

Comment: ```args``` это просто аргументы, которые вы передаёте при запуске программы, например ```моя_программа аргумент1```. Можно вообще не передавать никаких аргументов, а просто запустить вашу программу что и делает идея. Поэтому массив аргументов ( длина ) равно нулю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно также задать аргументы в IntellIJ IDEA, зайди в настройки запуска приложения `Edit Configuration` строка с названием `Program arguments`.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень интересно.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы будете запускать приложение с командной строки к примеру

```
java YourClass foo bar
```

то в метод main придут ваши параметры foo bar

Comment: А при двойном щелчке по джарнику, что прилетает?

Comment: массив нулевой длины

Answer (score 3):

`String[] args` это аргументы вашей программы, если запустите `java {YourClass} foo bar baz` то в массиве `args` будет `foo,bar,baz`